# Determine whether $D_4/Z(D_4)\otimes Z(D_4)$ is isomorphic to $D_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

Determine whether $D_4/Z(D_4)\otimes Z(D_4)$ is isomorphic to $D_4$.

**My attempt**

I found that the center $Z(D_4)$ is comprised of $I$ and $R^{2}$, and is normal to $D_4$, so $D_4/Z(D_4)$ is the group of the cosets: $\{IZ,rZ,RZ,R^2Z,R^3Z,RrZ,R^2rZ,R^3rZ\}$. Computing the cosets we find that some are duplicates, resulting in $D_4/Z(D_4)=\{Z,rZ,RZ,RrZ\}$
so
$$D_4/Z(D_4)\otimes Z(D_4)=\\\{\{I,R^2\}\otimes I,\{I,R^2\}\otimes R^2,\{r,rR^2\}\otimes I,\{r,rR^2\}\otimes R^2,\\\{R,R^3\}\otimes I,\{R,R^3\}\otimes R^2,\{Rr,rR\}\otimes I,\{Rr,rR\}\otimes R^2\}$$ has 8 elements like $D_4$.

Now I don't know how to associate to each and every element of $D_4/Z(D_4)\otimes Z(D_4)$ an element of $D_4$, knowing the properties $r^2=R^4=I$ and $RrR=r$.

Comment: By $\otimes$ do you mean the [nonabelian tensor product of groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_groups)?

Comment: Is it cross product of groups?

Comment: It seems likely that Lorenzo is working on the direct product
$$D_4/Z(D_4)\,\times\,Z(D_4).$$
This cannot be isomorphic to $D_4$, because this direct product is abelian whereas $D_4$ is not.

Comment: Yes I think that is a direct product, thank you. What is the difference between that and the tensor product? I didn't study it.

Comment: [Tensor product of modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules).

Comment: You may want to begin with [tensor products of abelian groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_abelian_groups). However, groupprops is mostly a reference site, and not really geared towards learning (at least that's the impression I have). Abelian groups should be seen simply as $\Bbb{Z}$-modules. We have results like $\Bbb{Z}_m\otimes\Bbb{Z}_n\simeq\Bbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

If by $\otimes$ you mean the classical tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ (it could be, since the groups you are tensoring are abelian), then the answer is clearly NO, since the tensor product of abelian groups is an abelian group. Moreover, your tensor product will have four distinct elements, and not eight (you forgot that you have some relations in the tensor product..)
. In fact $D_4/Z(D_4)\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ and $Z(D_4)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so your tensor product is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.

Comment: I don't get what are the relations I forgot... should I have made explicit $Z$? Anyway, if the distinct elements are 4 I conclude right away that there is no isomorphism since $D_4$ has order 8

Comment: First, the elements of a tensor product $A\otimes B$ of abelian groups are **sums of elementary tensors $a\otimes b$ (and definitely not pairs $(a,b)$). Second, the symbol $-\otimes -$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear. In particular, you have relations such as $(m\cdot a)\otimes b=a\otimes (m\cdot b)$...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get how this is related... (update: I rewrote the set)

Comment: @LorenzoB. In most textbooks on abstract algebra the symbol $\otimes$ is reserved for something called *the tensor product*. Judging from your writing, in your book this symbol denotes what everybody else calls the direct product, usually written with $\times$. I guess you had no way of knowing this :-(